# Google tag manager : Configuration and publication ok but not able to display tag on website

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-tag-manager

I have configure all my GTM account and create container, tags etc...

I have create a version and publish my container.
And when I want to see the result on my website all my code was encapsulated in div tag with style display none and visibility hidden:

```
 <div style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
   <script>$(window).load(function(){alert("window is loaded")});</script>
   </div>
```

do you know how i can fix that?

Comment: Did you find any solution? because I am facing the same issue. :(

Comment: Fix what? What are you trying to achieve? The script still executes, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

GTM loads the tags that you need separately, not inside a certain div. Check via the console if your tags are there. Besides, I'm not sure what this code about, are you sure it's related to GTM?