# Google tag manager div visibility is set to none

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

I have added google tag using GTM on my website.
But the contents of the tag are not visible as the style of the div inside which the tag div gets inserted is set as

```
style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"
```

```html
<div style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"><div><h1>djsf,mdfgn,jbgndf,kjbndk,ngjbhldf</h1></div></div>
```

My GTM tags are -

1) in the head

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>        (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({ 'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
            }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-KNMSG6F');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

2) in the body -

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KNMSG6F" height="0"
            width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Please help. This is just beginning of questions related to GTM i guess!!

Comment: What you want to see inside this tag if it's only sends user actions information and does not shows any output? It's intended to be hidden. You always can use `!important` in CSS. If you own tag, than just delete `style` attribute.

Comment: since it is my first tag, i have used just text inside it. where is the style for the div set? in fact the outer div, i don't know where it comes from.

Comment: my tag just contains - <h1>some text </h1>

Comment: @Justinas from where should I delete the style attribute?

Comment: This has been asked before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524031/google-tag-manager-configuration-and-publication-ok-but-not-able-to-display-ta, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364341/google-tag-manager-is-hiding-my-custom-html-tag-with-css) with no solution. I cannot reproduce the issue. Is there anything more you can tell us about your setup ? Google discourages adding/changing visible page content via GTM, but I am not aware that they actively try to prevent you from doing so.

Comment: @EikePierstorff i have seen it in a sample video where they do add header tag without changing any configuration and it works fine, so I tried. I am totally new to this so I can't give any other inputs. Although I can check any properties in GTM if that can help :| :(